# How to get always Pi as a number

Tags: built-in-symbols

Since this morning I have the following command to return `Pi` as a symbol in the value of `k`. Since `k` is then used as a parameter for a plot the `Plot` does not come out anymore... Can you tell me what I accidentally did and how can I solve this issue?

```
λ=6328 10^-9;
(*change this value to set new wavelength*)

k=(2 Pi)/λ
(* (250000000 π)/791 *)
```

Comment: Can you show an example of _"Since k is then used as a parameter for a plot the Plot does not come out anymore"_ ?

Comment: If you're merely feeding in `k` as part of the argument to a function for `Plot`, there is not particular reason to take a numerical value (i.e., an approximate value) of `Pi`  or `\[Lambda]` or `k`. *Mathematica* will be using numerical values of the variable, and when any approximate number is combined algebraically with an exact value, the result will automatically be approximate. So please do show us exactly what the `Plot` expression is that is giving trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Define a numerical version of π

```
pi = N @ Pi
(* 3.14159 *)

λ = 6328 10^-9;
k = (2 pi)/λ 
(* 992918. *)
```

Comment: I'd argue the proper thing here is to simply make lambda real just by adding a decimal, since it surely is  a real/inexact number anyway.